# Get values directly from app.config file to connection string

Tags: c#, string, connection-string, app-config

In my application I implement a dynamic connection string that get values directly from the `app.config` file. But before get values I assigned values to label text and the call it from connection string. I want to get that value directly from string without using label

This is my code

```
dbserverip.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serverip"].ToLower().Trim();
curport.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbport"].ToLower().Trim();
currentdb.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["defdatabase"].ToLower().Trim();
```

after I assigned values to labels, I called it from connection string like this:

```
string constring = string.Format(
    "datasource='{0}';port='{1}';database='{2}';username=uwloanmanmain;password=XXXXXXXX;Connect Timeout=180;Command Timeout=180",
    dbserverip.Text, curport.Text, currentdb.Text);
```

but I want to do this without using any labels. Just only using string values. How can I do this?

Comment: are you familiar with `Session` objects or you could store these in a `public static string dbserverip { get; set; };` for example.. look up how to declare and use `string variables` as well [MSDN C# Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx)

Comment: In that case, you need to define those values as string fields in your class, assign the values from the config file to those fields, and you're done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `dbserverip.Text` with `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serverip"].ToLower().Trim()`, `curport.Text` with `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbport"].ToLower().Trim()`, and `currentdb.Text` with `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["defdatabase"].ToLower().Trim()`

```
string constring = string.Format("datasource='{0}';port='{1}';database='{2}';username=uwloanmanmain;password=xxxxxxxxxxxx;Connect Timeout=180;Command Timeout=180", 
                       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serverip"].ToLower().Trim(), 
                       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbport"].ToLower().Trim(), 
                       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["defdatabase"].ToLower().Trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine in the place where you construct the connection string you don't have an access to the `ConfigurationManager`. The way I see to resolve this is to create a separate type/class, that once filled with data from config in the place where you now populate labels,  is available among types of your program.

And also for this kind of information may be useful to use [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: Yes. as you said i cant access configurationmanager where i construct connection string. thanks for your reply sir. i'll look in to securestring class

Answer (score 0):

You can use string variables like this.

```
string sdbserverip = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serverip"].ToLower().Trim();
string scurport = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbport"].ToLower().Trim();
string scurrentdb = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["defdatabase"].ToLower().Trim();

string constring = string.Format("datasource='{0}';port='{1}';database='{2}';username=uwloanmanmain;password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;Connect Timeout=180;Command Timeout=180", sdbserverip, scurport, scurrentdb);
```